# Policy Violation on Interstitial Ads

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I'm a web developer and I'm using webview android feature to develop android app of my website. Just a few hours back, I received a policy violation message for my Interstitial Ads. The message says that interstitial ad placement is resulting in accidental clicks. I have placed the interstitial ads when the app is opened and that might be the issue for accidental clicks.

My question is,

- Should I delay the interstitial ad by 7 or 10 seconds. The ad should pop up only if the user spends 7 seconds on my app with settimeout method. Should this be called policy violation or is it okay to settimeout on Interstitial open?
- I'm using banner ads and Interstitial ads with my webview app. Is there any other ad type that I can implement with the webview? I desperately want to implement the native ads but for that I will use Google adsense from my website.

I have not tried anything because first I want to take advice from the community because Adsense is very strict. I believe I should not do experiments without proper research.